# ArrayList is arriving empty in Android's handleMessage() method

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-service, android-service-binding

In a service I'm populating an ArrayList, which I then return to the calling activity:

In service (here, resultArrayList contains items and is of class `ArrayList<MyObjs>`):

```
public class DataFetchService extends BaseService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        super.onHandleIntent(intent);

        // Do some work here that populates resultArrayList...

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(BaseService.RESULT_OBJ, resultArrayList);
        message.setData(bundle);

        try {
            final Messenger messenger = startIntent.getParcelableExtra(BaseService.PARAM_MESSENGER);
            messenger.send(message);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            L.p("Help!");
        }
```

From BaseService:

```
public class BaseService extends IntentService {
    protected ArrayList<MyObjs> resultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Yada yada...
```

In the activity's handleMessage():

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(final Message msg) {

    final Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final ArrayList<MyObjs> nodes = (ArrayList<MyObjs>) bundle.getSerializable(BaseService.RESULT_OBJ);

    if (nodes == null) {
        //App never enters this
        return
    }

    if (nodes.size() == 0) {
        // Always enters here!
        // If I set a breakpoint here, the IDE tells me nodes size is 1
    }
```

The weird thing is that if I set a breakpoint inside the `if (nodes.size == 0) {` code, the IDE shows that `nodes` does contain items (says size = 1 and I can expand it and see the variables), even though it enters that.

Any idea what could be the issue? Could this be a race condition between other services sending data back to handleMessage()?

Comment: When you step through with your debugger, does it still enter the `if`?

Comment: Show your initialization of resultArrayList

Comment: clean and rebuild your project..

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post an answer but I'm not sure this is the problem. "size" is a method of ArrayList so it should be `if(size() == 0)`. I'm not sure you could build the way it is in the question so that may just be a typo. Also, far from a Java expert here but my understanding is that `if(isEmpty())` would be a better way to go. Either way, it can't hurt to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Just updated the question.

Comment: @shmosel if I set a breakpoint before the `if (nodes.size() == 0) {` and step in it works erroneously as well.

Comment: @barq resultArrayList is a `protected` member variable of the service's parent class. This is the init: `protected ArrayList<Node> resultNodes = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @barq Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: Why do you need `resultNodes`? It does not look like you ever use it. You send and receive two different lists

Comment: @cricket_007 That's a typo, sorry

Comment: Okay, so you are asking why a list is empty without showing the important piece of `Do some work here that populates resultArrayList`?

Comment: @cricket_007 That part seems irrelevant. The ArrayList HAS data before sending it back to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain about the causes of this error, but creating a new `ArrayList<>` before sending from the service seems to fix it.

So the following makes it work:

```
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // Created this new ArrayList
    final ArrayList<MyObjs> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add items to the new ArrayList
    newArrayList.addAll(resultArrayList);

    // Send the new ArrayList and NOT the other one.
    bundle.putSerializable(BaseService.RESULT_OBJ, newArrayList);
    message.setData(bundle);

    try {
        final Messenger messenger = startIntent.getParcelableExtra(BaseService.PARAM_MESSENGER);
        messenger.send(message);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        L.p("Help!");
    }
```